# How do I query schema bound views?

Tags: sql-server, view

I can list all views in SQL Server 2008 by using

```
SELECT * FROM sys.views
```

What I want to do is to list only the views that are schema bound. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.views 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsSchemaBound') = 1
```

Comment: This is great, I'm curious now if there is a similar way to look for schema bound functions as well.

Comment: @jpierson: replace `sys.views` with `sys.objects` and add `AND type = 'FN'`.

Comment: I get `Could not find stored procedure 'IsSchemaBound'` on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: FWIW, if you prefer to use strongly-typed columns instead of the loosely typed `OBJECTPROPERTY()` function, then you can instead use `m.is_schema_bound` in `sys.views AS v INNER JOIN sys.modules AS m ON v.object_id = m.object_id`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find the schema bound views for a specific table. This worked for me in SQL Server 2019.

```
select  distinct
  o.type, SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id), o.name
--, *
from sys.sql_dependencies d
  inner join sys.objects o
  on d.object_id = o.object_id
where d.class = 1 -- OBJECT_OR_COLUMN_REFERENCE_SCHEMA_BOUND
and d.referenced_major_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable')
order by 1, 2, 3
;
```